# node mysql is it possible to get timestamp of newly created row

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mysql-insert-id

I have the following node function to INSERT a row into my mysql rds:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO items SET item_id = ?, item_name = ?";
connection.query(sql, [event.itemId, event.itemName, function (error, results, fields) {

    console.log(results);
    connection.release();

    if (error) {
        context.done(error);
    } else {
        // continue...
    }
});
```

items also has a date_created column with default value being CURRENT_TIMESTAMP upon creation.

Is there anyway to get the value of date_created without doing another query?  Not being that familiar with node/mysql I'm wondering if when a row is created the row values will be returned?

If not, then I have two choices, one is to do another query to get the date_created or just to add the date_created field myself when creating the row.  Wondering what is the best practice in this case.  Not sure if doing two queries will be costly.

EDIT #1

The results prints out as follows:

```
{
  "fieldCount": 0,
  "affectedRows": 1,
  "insertId": 0,
  "serverStatus": 2,
  "warningCount": 0,
  "message": "",
  "protocol41": true,
  "changedRows": 0
}
```

Comment: What does it print in the console when you do `console.log(results);` ?

Comment: edited to show results printout

Comment: according to your result,it shows that insertId=0.It might not have updated in your db... try with INSERT INTO items(item_id, item_name) VALUES(?,?)

Comment: Database entry is being successfully added. Not sure why it says that. item_id is a field I define and enter and also primary key. Not AI.

Comment: looking at the documentation the insertId is only returned if using auto incrementing which I am not.